# Tex symbol in xaxis using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can print `0`, `\pi/4`, `3\pi/8`, `\pi/2` in the x-axis when plotting `\sin(x)` with gnuplot in the range `[0, \pi/2]`.

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.